# iPhone UISegmentedControl button states on black UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, uitoolbar

I have a UISegmentedControl on a black UIToolbar.  I have set the style to Bar and set the background color to clear (also tried black).  I have tried setting the tintColor clear (also tried black).  My buttons turn black to match the black UIToolbar.  However, the buttons no longer indicate a clicked state like they do when the UISegmentedControl is the default blue/grey.  What do I have to do to make the buttons indicate a black/grey clicked state?  Please let me know.  Code used so far to set the color of the UISegmentedControl:

```
viewTypeSelection.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
viewTypeSelection.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not a perfect solution, this works pretty well

```
    // set the color
viewTypeSelection.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
viewTypeSelection.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

The buttons have state change and it looks OK.  Here is a post that has a few more details and might help someone looking for a similar solution:

[UISegmentedControl black?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=541508)

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I needed (and so simple "once you know how")

Answer (score 0):

You may have set the color of the bar with `tintColor` instead of setting `barStyle` like so:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```